# ssh stops working on CentOS 8 (GCE VM)

Tags: ssh, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, ssh-keys, google-compute-engine

ssh stops working on CentOS 8 (GCE VM)

I had ssh working correctly with a pub/private key pair working just fine for two days on a GCE CentOS 8 VM, and it stopped working.

Now I get:

`Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

So it was working, meaning everything was setup, configured correctly, with all permissions working correctly, and now it does not work, so it's not the configuration.  Nothing changed in the configuration.

I have the same setup working on CentOS 7, and it just keeps going and going, has never gone down, stopped working or had a problem.

The configuration is correct, I checked file and directory permissions.

```
$cd $HOME/.ssh
$ls -al .
```

Results:

```
drwx------.  3 user group  156 Oct 17 10:11 .
drwxrwx---. 12 user group 4096 Oct 17 10:09 ..
-rw-------.  1 user group  197 Oct 17 10:09 authorized_keys
```

I generated a key like so (in cygwin), and put the .pub contents on the GCE VM in /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

```
ssh-keygen -f id_ed25519 -o -a 100 -t ed25519 -C "from:cygwin"
```

It was working earlier in the day, and now it's not.

My connection script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=x.x.x.x
LOCAL_KEYFILE="/c/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519"
REMOTE_USER='user'
ssh -v -i $LOCAL_KEYFILE $REMOTE_USER@$IP
```

$systemctl status sshd.service

```
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-10-17 10:19:12 UTC; 17ms ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 2504 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 26213)
   Memory: 1.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─2504 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -oCiphers=aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc -oMACs=hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.c>
Oct 17 10:19:12 host_name systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 17 10:19:12 host_name sshd[2504]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 17 10:19:12 host_name sshd[2504]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Oct 17 10:19:12 host_name systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
```

verbose output when trying to connect:

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /g/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /g/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1    <== I dunno what this is, I don't have this file local
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 34.82.235.87:22 as 'proc'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:nfWd1FFBjYKQ7G7j4hkftEfB8UowSKkwfJzC2T8UF1g
debug1: Host '34.82.235.87' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<another-unrelated-user>/.ssh/known_hosts:11  <== why is it reference another user here?
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /g/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:7o0XJjVnZLuzi+fO1NUUkFKpwKqw87u208IBy53zHcI explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,null>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /g/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:7o0XJjVnZLuzi+fO1NUUkFKpwKqw87u208IBy53zHcI explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

---

I found some articles that said I should run these commands, so I did:

```
restorecon -Rv /home/user/.ssh/
restorecon -Rv /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

and then after running each one, I restarted sshd, and tried to connect, and got the same results (same error message).
restart command:

`systemctl restart sshd.service`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, this is baffling.

Nothing has changed in the GCE firewall settings, port 22 is open, and I can connect to a VM using configured with the same network.

I can connect via ssh, when open a window in the browser through:
`https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instancesDetail/zones/us-west1-b/instances/<instance>?project=<project-name>`

I turned off selinux with:
`setenforce 0`

and in `/etc/selinux/config, I set **SELINUX=disabled**
and restarted the VM, and no such luck.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment. This is not an answer but rather to clarify the question. How are you adding the public key to the instance? Are you adding it to the instance/project [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#edit-ssh-metadata) ? Do you have [OS-Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) enabled (should not be) ? Are you able to SSH using the [SDK commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) such as from [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/)? Are you able